# odoc (documentation generator for OCaml) remove 'Stdlib' prefix

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, ocamldoc

I'm using [odoc](https://github.com/ocaml/odoc#odoc---), along with [dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune#dune---a-composable-build-system) to generate documentation for a library. This is made by doing: `dune build @doc`

However, this generates signatures like:

```
val print : Stdlib.Format.formatter -> t -> unit
```

While what i would like is:

```
val print : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
```

OCamldoc used to provide the **-hide** option which could do exactly this. Does odoc have something similar? If yes, how to use it from dune?

Optionnaly, it would be perfect to have a link to the Format module of the Stdlib but this is maybe asking too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, odoc did not have something similar at the time i asked the question.
However it seems that now it is (or soon wille be) the case, thanks to this [PR](https://github.com/ocaml/odoc/pull/677), which allows you to specify which modules to open by default by doing:

```
odoc compile --open=Stdlib
```